# Can I send IMs to an AIM user through the Google Talk app?

Tags: google-talk, aim

I linked my Google Talk and AIM accounts on the GMail website, but it doesn't look like my AIM buddies are showing up in the Android Google Talk application. Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe the Google Chat client supports this. Here are some alternatives:

1. [Nimbuzz](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nimbuzz%3Afree-calls-messaging/com.nimbuzz)
2. [Meebo](http://www.appbrain.com/app/meebo-im/com.meebo)
3. [eBuddy Messager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ebuddy-messenger/com.ebuddy.android) (via @Matt)

Comment: [eBuddy Messenger](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ebuddy-messenger/com.ebuddy.android) is another good one.

Answer (score 1):

Try chatting with your AIM contacts through the web interface first.  Make sure your Google contacts list contains them and that they are set to show in chat "Always".